# Strange issue: Some classes don't get their styles from CSS file

Tags: html, css

## Description

The problem is, when I leave only 1 pages css. It's ok

http://jsfiddle.net/RcJX5578J/3/

[image]

But when I use is all-in-one css file (combined result of all pages' css styles.) some divs dont get their styles from CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/RcJX5578J/1/

[image]

## Question is...

I'd want to know, what blocks class `.cont_title` when I use all css styles together? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second fiddle, you have an invalid set of characters just above your `.cont_title` class. Removing the invalid characters fixes the issue you're seeing.

```
...
.row:hover .remove{
    opacity: 1;
}â€‹   <-- Some weird characters here

.cont_title {
    height: 40px;
    ...
```

Comment: That's the problem. The [css validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator) calls this out as: `Lexical error at line 891, column 2. Encountered: "?" (63), after : "" }???????? .cont_title`...

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu - Interesting. What editor are you using? It could be an encoding issue.

Comment: Netbeans:) Yeah, maybe encoding related.

Comment: Is that at a boundary between files? I'm guessing a wayward [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu, you don't need to see it in your editor.  Just wipe out that single line and retype the `}`... did it work?